local_costmap from nav2 is not displayed in rviz2
I've tried to view local_costmap from /local_costmap/costmap topic in rviz2, but it doesn't work in ROS2 Humble because of following error:
"[INFO] [1714830442.379829286] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'odom' at time 1714830436.260 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full'"
Launch command:
ros2 launch nav2_bringup navigation.launch.py

In addition, it works in ROS2 Foxy container. Also, I've tried to use CycloneDDS instead of FastRTPS because of bug: https://github.com/open-navigation/navigation2/issues/3014


Try to correct the QoS settings used by the odom topic and if it doesnt work then maybe your fixed frame id in rviz is incorrect.
It also can happen if your odom topic is not present in the same tf tree as your fixed frame.
