PointCloud2 xarco implementation
I'm trying to use a lidar for my simulation and I want to receive data from it. In the XACRO file I used the following plugin but the topic won't show in ros2 topic list. Here is the lidar code snippets from my xacro file:
<!-- Velodyne VLP-16 LiDAR Sensor Link and Joint -->
<link name="velodyne_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0.0001" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="velodyne_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/> <!-- Adjust the position as needed -->
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="velodyne_link"/>
</joint>

<!-- Gazebo plugin for Velodyne VLP-16 LiDAR -->
<gazebo reference="velodyne_link">
  <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="velodyne_lidar_sensor">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <visualize>true</visualize>
    <update_rate>20</update_rate>
    <ray>
      <scan>
        <horizontal>
          <samples>1800</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-3.141592653589793</min_angle>
          <max_angle>3.141592653589793</max_angle>
        </horizontal>
        <vertical>
          <samples>16</samples>
          <resolution>1</resolution>
          <min_angle>-0.2617993877991494</min_angle>
          <max_angle>0.2617993877991494</max_angle>
        </vertical>
      </scan>
      <range>
        <min>0.1</min>
        <max>100.0</max>
        <resolution>0.01</resolution>
      </range>
      <noise>
        <type>gaussian</type>
        <mean>0.0</mean>
        <stddev>0.01</stddev>
      </noise>
    </ray>
    <plugin name="gazebo_ros_gpu_laser" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
      <topicName>/drone/velodyne_points</topicName>
      <frameName>velodyne_link</frameName>
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>20</updateRate>
      <outputType>sensor_msgs/PointCloud2</outputType>
    </plugin>
  </sensor>
</gazebo>

Maybe this is wrong:       <outputType>sensor_msgs/PointCloud2</outputType>
Full XACRO file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<robot name="sjtu_drone"
  xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1.477"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.1152" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.1152" iyz="0" izz="0.218"/>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="sjtu_drone_collision">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0   0   0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.stl"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual name="sjtu_drone_visual">
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0   0   0.04"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="file://$(find sjtu_drone_description)/models/sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/>
        <!-- <mesh filename="package://sjtu_drone/quadrotor_4.dae"/> -->
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="sonar_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="sonar_link" />
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="sonar_link"/>


  <joint name="front_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.2 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="front_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="front_cam_link"/>

  <joint name="bottom_cam_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="0 1.570796326794897 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="base_link" />
    <child link="bottom_cam_link" />
  </joint>
  <link name="bottom_cam_link"/>
  
<!-- LiDAR Sensor Link and Joint -->
<link name="lidar_link">
  <inertial>
    <mass value="0.1"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001"/>
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="gray"/>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.05"/>
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>

<joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
  <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.1" rpy="0 0 0"/> <!-- Aligned forward with a slight elevation -->
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="lidar_link"/>
</joint>





  <gazebo>
    <plugin name='simple_drone' filename='libplugin_drone.so'>
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <rosNamespace>drone</rosNamespace>
      <imuTopic>imu</imuTopic>
      <rollpitchProportionalGain>10.0</rollpitchProportionalGain>
      <rollpitchDifferentialGain>5.0</rollpitchDifferentialGain>
      <rollpitchLimit>0.5</rollpitchLimit>
      <yawProportionalGain>2.0</yawProportionalGain>
      <yawDifferentialGain>1.0</yawDifferentialGain>
      <yawLimit>1.5</yawLimit>
      <velocityXYProportionalGain>5.0</velocityXYProportionalGain>
      <velocityXYDifferentialGain>2.3</velocityXYDifferentialGain>
      <velocityXYLimit>2</velocityXYLimit>
      <velocityZProportionalGain>5.0</velocityZProportionalGain>
      <velocityZIntegralGain>0.0</velocityZIntegralGain>
      <velocityZDifferentialGain>1.0</velocityZDifferentialGain>
      <velocityZLimit>-1</velocityZLimit>
      <positionXYProportionalGain>1.1</positionXYProportionalGain>
      <positionXYDifferentialGain>0.0</positionXYDifferentialGain>
      <positionXYIntegralGain>0.0</positionXYIntegralGain>
      <positionXYLimit>5</positionXYLimit>
      <positionZProportionalGain>1.0</positionZProportionalGain>
      <positionZDifferentialGain>0.2</positionZDifferentialGain>
      <positionZIntegralGain>0.0</positionZIntegralGain>
      <positionZLimit>-1</positionZLimit>
      <maxForce>30</maxForce>
      <motionSmallNoise>0.05</motionSmallNoise>
      <motionDriftNoise>0.03</motionDriftNoise>
      <motionDriftNoiseTime>5.0</motionDriftNoiseTime>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- Sensors -->
  <!-- IMU sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name='sensor_imu' type='imu'>
      <always_on> 1 </always_on>
      <visualize>1</visualize>
      <update_rate> 100 </update_rate>
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <plugin name='imu' filename='libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so'>
        <initial_orientation_as_reference>false</initial_orientation_as_reference>
      </plugin>
      <imu>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <rate>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0 </stddev>
          </rate>
          <accel>
            <mean> 0 </mean>
            <stddev> 0.00 </stddev>
          </accel>
        </noise>
      </imu>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- Sonar sensor in 100fps -->
  <gazebo reference="sonar_link">
    <sensor name="sonar" type="ray">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>5</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1.000000</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.12</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.12</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.02</min>
          <max>10</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.01</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="sonar" filename="libgazebo_ros_ray_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=sonar</remapping>
        </ros>
        <output_type>sensor_msgs/Range</output_type>
        <radiation_type>ultrasound</radiation_type>
        <frame_name>sonar_link</frame_name>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

  <gazebo reference="front_cam_link">
    <sensor name="front_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>2.09</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>60</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="camera_front" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_front</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_front_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>front</camera_name>
        <frame_name>front_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


  <!-- downward looking camera -->
  <gazebo reference="bottom_cam_link">
    <sensor name="down_camera" type="camera">
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>360</height>
          <format>R8G8B8</format>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.1</near>
          <far>100</far>
        </clip>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.005</stddev>
        </noise>
      </camera>
      <always_on>1</always_on>
      <update_rate>15</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <plugin name="camera_bottom" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>image_raw:=camera_bottom</remapping>
          <remapping>camera_info:=camera_bottom_info</remapping>
        </ros>
        <camera_name>bottom</camera_name>
        <frame_name>bottom_cam_link</frame_name>
        <hack_baseline>0.07</hack_baseline>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>

<gazebo reference="lidar_link">
    <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="velodyne_laser">
      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>1200</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-3.14159</min_angle> <!-- -180 degrees -->
            <max_angle>3.14159</max_angle>  <!-- 180 degrees -->
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>15</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.261799</min_angle> <!-- -15 degrees -->
            <max_angle>0.261799</max_angle>  <!-- 15 degrees -->
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.20</min>
          <max>100</max>
          <resolution>0.001</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.00</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="point_cloud" filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=/lidar/points</remapping>
        </ros>
        <frame_name>base_scan</frame_name>
        <min_range>0.05</min_range>
        <max_range>100.0</max_range>
        <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>




  <gazebo reference="base_link">
    <sensor name="gps" type="gps">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>30</update_rate>
      <gps>
        <position_sensing>
          <horizontal>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <noise type="gaussian">
              <mean>0.0</mean>
              <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
            </noise>
          </vertical>
        </position_sensing>
      </gps>
      <plugin name="gps" filename="libgazebo_ros_gps_sensor.so">
        <ros>
          <namespace>/gps</namespace>
          <remapping>~/out:=data</remapping>
        </ros>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>


Try velodyne plugin. If you want to use gpu, set ray_type to gpu_ray, if not, set it to ray. The rest of the specifications depend on your project but here is an example of 3d lidar implemenataion in gazebo:
<gazebo reference="${frame_prefix}link">
    <sensor type="${ray_type}" name="${frame_prefix}sensor">

      <visualize>false</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
            <samples>1200</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>${-radians(180)}</min_angle>
            <max_angle>${radians(180)}</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>15</samples>
            <resolution>1.0</resolution>
            <min_angle>${-radians(15.0)}</min_angle>
            <max_angle>${radians(15.0)}</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.20</min>
          <max>100</max>
          <resolution>0.001</resolution>
        </range>
        <noise>
          <type>gaussian</type>
          <mean>0.0</mean>
          <stddev>0.00</stddev>
        </noise>
      </ray>
      <plugin name="point_cloud" filename="libgazebo_ros_velodyne_laser.so">
        <ros>
          <remapping>~/out:=/lidar/points</remapping>
        </ros>
        <frame_name>${parent}</frame_name>
        <min_range>0.05</min_range>
        <max_range>100.0</max_range>
        <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>


i've changed it now to also use gpu but it still doesn't public a topic in ros2, you can check the xacro file, I've edited the question to add that too

Now it works, the only issue i have is that in Rviz2 i can't see the points because: [rviz2-1] [INFO] [1716644755.881455898] [rviz2]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'world' at time 1198.162 for reason 'discarding message because the queue is full' even tho the frame name is <frame_name>base_scan</frame_name>. I will try to decrease the samples and i hope it won't affect it badly. Once again thanks @fatemeh_p (also the last edit on the post has the correct implementation).

Try my answer for pointcloud topic in this question: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/111008/local-costmap-from-nav2-is-not-displayed-in-rviz2/111013#111013

If the answer solved your problem, please accept it
